# Retornar dados de tabelas diferentes em uma view - Laravel (Resolvido)

Tags: laravel

**Solução do problema:** Nesse exemplo, estou retornando na view de usuário, dados referentes à 2 tabelas diferentes (Intro, About), que poderão ser recuperadas a partir de um @foreach

Exemplo: View usuario.index

```
@foreach($intros as $intro)
    {{$intro->title_intro}}
    {{$intro->desc_intro}}
@endforeach
@foreach($abouts $about )
    {{$about ->title_about}}
    {{$about ->desc_about}}
@endforeach
```

**Controller do usuário:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Intro;
use App\About;

class UserController extends Controller

{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.index',
        [
           'intros' => Intro::paginate(5),
           'abouts' => About::paginate(5)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return view('caminho.nomeDaView')->with(['info1' => model::metodo($dado), 'info2' => model::metodo($dado2) ... ]);`

e por ai vai

Comment: Pera, ainda não consegui entender... Desculpe rs
depois do ->with, esse 'info1' seria referente ao que? E após o model:: essa parte: método($dado) seria referente ao que? Agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: info1 é referente ao nome do array que vc vai visualizar na view, o método, é o método po... Quanto vc conhece de orientação a objeto?

Comment: Básico/Intermediário... só que, não tenho muita experiência com o laravel fiquei confuso sobre qual método iria chamar ali... Desse jeito, é dada a informação que a variável intro é indefinida

return view('user.index')->with( [ 'intros' => Intro::index($intro), 'abouts' => About::index($abouts) ]);

Comment: é só fazer assim: `return view('user.index', ['intros' => Intro::paginate[5],'abouts' => About::paginate[5], 'skills' => Skill::paginate[5]]);` claro pode colocar tudo isso em uma variavel e passar ai também melhor inclusive. O método também é válido, mas, acho assim melhor (pura opinião)

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui e deu certo dessa forma Virgilio, muito obrigado! E ao Hanania também, por tirar um tempinho pra tentar me ajudar... :)
só o [] que troquei pelo () porque tinha dado erro mas de resto está tudo certinho heheh

Answer (score 0):

O seu retorno deve ser assim:

```
return view('user.index', 
    [
        'intros' => Intro::paginate(5), 
        'abouts' => About::paginate(5),
        'skills' => Skill::paginate(5)
    ]);
```

Para um melhor entendimento, leia sobre na documentação do [Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views)
Depois, na view, é só acessar o dado desejado pela Key desse array.